# Help with commas

Tags: grammar, commas

Recently I found myself in a situation where I was unsure about comma usage. The sentence was *Cereals can be extremely nutritious, for example, Frosted Flakes*.

Now is the usage of the comma before and after *for example* incorrect? I am not particularly concerned about whether or not there is a better way to rephrase the sentence, but I want to know whether it is grammatically correct for me to place the commas there or not. If so, can somebody explain why.

Comment: There's a handful of ways to punctuate this sentence. This is one of them. None of them are grammatically correct or grammatically incorrect, however. Punctuation is not grammar. This sen, tence;righthere Is PER!!!!!fectly grammatical English. "Grammar" is not a catch-all term to mean "anything and everything related to language". It has a very specific meaning. And commas are in no way, shape or form part of that meaning. For starters, there's no commas in speech. And no letters, for that matter.

Comment: The sentence would look and sound very odd without a comma before 'for example'.

Answer (score -1):

‘...nutritious, for example Frosted Flakes.’

I believe that would be the proper punctuation without any restructuring of your sentence.

Comment: Why would you think so?

Comment: Honestly, because it looks correct that way. I don’t study grammar (or punctuation @RegDwight :D) so I’m not sure what the reason would be. I do read/write a lot, however, and have a natural inclination for editing.

Comment: If there were multiple cereals listed as examples, it would be written “...nutritious, for example Frosted Flakes and Cheerios”; or “...Flakes, Cheerios, and Lucky Charms.”

Comment: It's more common to use a comma both before and after *for example*. There is no *proper* punctuation here (it's a matter of style), but your punctuation is uncommon and shouldn't be suggested as how it *should* be done.